# Rbind function in R is not working as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

The dataset comes from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/

I removed the whitespaces of headers in winequality_red to make it the same as winequality_white so I can use them in `rbind` without any complaint.

I am trying to combine wine_red and wine_white using `rbind`. However, `rbind` is not combining them properly and only assigning values from the first argument in the `rbind()` call.

I have tried using `merge` and other functions but I think rbind should work just fine. It seems that I just cannot find a way.

```
red_wine <- read.csv2("/Users/gansaikhanshur/Documents/R/FinalProject/winequality-red.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
white_wine <- read.csv2("/Users/gansaikhanshur/Documents/R/FinalProject/winequality-white.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
white_wine$wineType <- "white"
red_wine$wineType <- "red"
wine <- rbind(white_wine, red_wine)
```

So in this example, wine would contain only white_wine not red_wine. But I want to have white_wine and red_wine together.

Comment: I downloaded the dataset, imported them into R. Added `wineType` in both the data by `white_wine$wineType <- "white";red_wine$wineType <- "red"` and then did `wine <- rbind(white_wine, red_wine)` and I have both the wines together in `wine`. I could check it by doing `table(wine$wineType)`. I did not do any operation (like removing whitespaces etc) on column names at all.

Comment: @RonakShah would you mind pasting your code here please, Because mine is actually not working haha. Thank you

Comment: `red_wine <- read.csv2("/Users/ronak/Downloads/winequality-red.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE);white_wine <- read.csv2("/Users/ronak/Downloads/winequality-white.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE);
white_wine$wineType <- "white";red_wine$wineType <- "red";wine <- rbind(red_wine, white_wine); table(wine$wineType)
`

Answer (score 1):

In original datasets, variables are separated by ";" not ",". So I tried these scripts when importing them.

```
red_wine = read.csv("winequality-red.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
white_wine = read.csv("winequality-white.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
```

I just added `sep = ";"` arguments in the end of `read.csv()`. And it seems to be working properly. Please try this.

In your case file paths would be different. So scripts down below would work in your working directory.

```
red_wine = read.csv("/Users/gansaikhanshur/Documents/R/FinalProject/winequality-red.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
white_wine = read.csv("/Users/gansaikhanshur/Documents/R/FinalProject/winequality-white.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ";")
white_wine$wineType <- "white"
red_wine$wineType <- "red"
wine <- rbind(white_wine, red_wine)
```

I hope you find this helpful.